# Curious results using multi_match query in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch 7.3. I am making a query against multiple fields using an "universal" search box. E.g. I intend users to just type in a search query without trying to fill in specific search boxes for specific fields.

On my part to reduce complexity I search across few selected fields only for this use case. Let's say name, address.

```
  // Target of copy_to of multiple fields
  address:
    type: text  

  // Target of copy_to of multiple fields
  name:
    type: text
```

I am using the following query,

```
"query": {

    "bool": {
        "should": [{
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "chantz auburn",
                "fields": ["address", "name"],
                "type": "best_fields",
                "operator": "or"
            }
        }, {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "chantz auburn",
                "fields": ["address", "name"],
                "type": "phrase_prefix",
                "operator": "or"
            }
        }],
        "minimum_should_match": "1"
    }

}
```

With this I would expect to get the first hit to be a document with,

```
name: chantz lasts
address 9090 auburn drive KY
```

But instead I see stuff like,

```
name: chantz hasts
address 1122 castllight drive KY

name: chantz blasts
address 5656 suma pl CA
```

Basically no results at least in the first 10 hits that should match terms present in both the fields. i.e.

```
name: chantz lasts
address 9090 auburn drive KY
```

If I switch the order of the query from `chantz auburn` to `auburn chantz` then I get similar results but this time with address having `auburn` in them but the name does not have `chantz` in it.

I tried `cross_fields` as well. Not sure what am I missing here?

Comment: You could also include [explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) information from the search endpoint, that should put some more light here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dot not reproduce your problem in local ( but with only 3 dummy documents, my relevancy is crooked :p )

But here some hint about your query :

1/ Your `phrase_prefix` multi-match can work only if all the terms of the query are in the same order in the same field. For example `chantz las` will match `chantz lasts` but `chantz auburn` will match no document since `chantz` is in the name field and `auburn` in the address field. So quite not sure it will work as you intended

2/ If you use the `best_field` type for multi-match the score will be the score of the "most matching" field. So in your case, if `auburn` is a quite common term in your index ( if many users live here ) then the most matching field will be `name`. So all your document will be sorted in the score of the name field, and since all your example documents are 2-terms length document, they will all have the same score. I think that all your documents have the same score. So you need to use the `cross_field` type.

But there is something weird about your case since `cross_field` type does not seem to work and you say that changing the query term order change your result list, ( this should not happen with standard mapping/tokenization on a multi-match query). So could you add the mappings and settings of your index in your question? We need them to help you and resolve your problem.

Comment: I was actually able to use cross_fields, seems like I copied the wrong ES query which was generated by the app I was using.